# What is the best way of converting NON-String type to String type in Swift, using initializer vs "\()"?

Tags: swift

I wanted convert a value type that conform to **BinaryFloatingPoint** to **String**, but I noticed there is no initializer for that available from xCode! I used `"\()"` in this down code, but I what to know is the only way to converting?

```
func test<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(value: T) {
    
    let stringValue: String = "\(value)"

    print(stringValue)
    
}
```

---

From the other hand I tried to convert a **BinaryInteger** to **String**, I found out that there is an initializer for that, But I thought why would we need that initializer even? because we could use `"\()"` also here without bothering ourself if there is or there is not an initializer!

```
func test<T: BinaryInteger>(value: T) {
    
    let stringValue: String = String(value)

    print(stringValue)
    
}
```

**Goal:** So I want to know why we need **String** initializer, when we could convert all most everything with `"\()"`?

Comment: Not every type can be initializer with String initializer. Try changing BinaryInteger to BinaryFloatingPoint

Comment: @LeoDabus: when we can not initialize with String, what should we do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not the only way of converting it. You can add another constrain to your generic type requiring it to conform to `LosslessStringConvertible` as well. Note that all `BinaryFloatingPoint` types conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` but not all of them conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible` (i.e CGFloat).

If you don't care about your method supporting `CGFloat` you can constrain it `LosslessStringConvertible` otherwise you need to use `CustomStringConvertible`'s `String(describing:)` initializer.

---

This will not support `CGFloat`

```
func test<T: BinaryFloatingPoint & LosslessStringConvertible>(value: T) {        
    let stringValue = String(value)
    print(stringValue)
    
}
```

---

This will support all `BinaryFloatingPoint` floating point types. Note that you don't need to constrain to `CustomStringConvertible`. It is only for demonstration purposes.

```
func test<T: BinaryFloatingPoint & CustomStringConvertible>(value: T) {
    let stringValue = String(describing: value)
    print(stringValue)
}
```

You can also make `CGFloat` conform to `LosslessStringConvertible` as well:

```
extension CGFloat: LosslessStringConvertible {
    private static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    public init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let number = CGFloat.formatter.number(from: description) as? CGFloat else { return nil }
        self = number
    }
}
```

This will allow you to support all floating point types with your generic method and use the String initializer as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why we need String initializer, when we could convert all most everything with `"\()"`

Ask yourself what `"\()"` does. By default it calls an initializer! Namely `String(describing:)`. This in turn depends on CustomStringConvertible etc. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init

Comment: No!, there is no description available for BinaryFloatingPoint also there is not initializer available for BinaryFloatingPoint for String! but still `"\()"` can convert it without accessing to description or any initializer. I thing there is some other thing going on with `"\()"`

Comment: Read over the docs matt linked. It includes the various steps, including "an unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard library" which is done for types that do not conform to any of the available protocols. But you don't have to guess. You can read the stdlib source for the function. If you trace it down it's handled by `_adHocPrint_unlocked()`: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift#L300-L398

Comment: If you want to see precisely how string interpolation is implemented, see https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/StringInterpolation.swift